# Add Bearer token option in swagger for particular version in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger in the Web API application. I have multiple versions of API, but I want to apply Bearer token option to version 2 only. There is no authentication for both versions. Here is my code:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v2" });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,         
    });
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way of solving this, I assume you have a prefix for controller version v1 as prefix, then what you can do is:

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        if (context.ApiDescription.RelativePath.StartsWith("v2"))
        {
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter()
            {
                @In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
            });
        }

    }
}
```

and use it

```
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
});
```

This will only add Bearer field to v2 end points.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can install [NSwag.AspNetCore](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiAhYCK4eDpAhXWQxUIHY6vD64QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nuget.org%2Fpackages%2FNSwag.AspNetCore%2F&usg=AOvVaw1OtEKLzP1KJjE33HfPxhw8) and add different options with different versions.

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument(a =>
{
    a.DocumentName = "v1";
    a.Version = "v1";
});

services.AddSwaggerDocument(a =>
{
    a.DocumentName = "v2";
    a.Version = "v2";
    a.AddSecurity("bearer", new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "jwt",
        In = NSwag.OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Type = NSwag.OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "bearer"
    });
});
```

```
app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3();
```

You can read more about it in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-nswag-middleware).